# How can I insert data from table row by onClick in React

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am new in React and I am trying to insert data from a table row, but when clicking on the 'Add table row' button no data has been taken from the inserting row.
Here is an example code:

app.js:

```
const app = () => {
    const [tableRows, setTableRows] = useState([]);
    const [newTableRow, setNewTableRow] = useState([
        {
            rowCol1 = null,
            rowCol2 = null,
            rowCol3 = null,
            //...
        }
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        GetDataFromBackEndEndpoint().then(data => {setTableRows(data)})
    }, []);

    const createAction = useCallback(
        // empty object received from the table component
        (newItem)  => {
            CallBackEndEndpoint(newItem);
        });

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Table Rows Data</h1>
            <TableComponent
                data={tableRows}
            />
                
            <h1>Add new table row</h1>
            <TableComponent
                data={newTableRow}
                onCreate={createAction}
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

TableComponent.js:

```
const TableComponent = ({
    data,
    onCreate
}) => {
    const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
            { 
                // table rows data received from a backend service 
            },
            Cell: table => {
                return (
                    <button
                        onClick={() => onCreate(table.row.original)} // empty object
                    >
                        Add new table row
                    </button>
                );
            }
        ], [onCreate] 
    );

    // ...
}
```

What am I missing to get the values inserted in the "Add table row" cells?

Thanks in advance!